# How do you disable the double tap keyboard popup in a UITextField?

Tags: iphone, ios4, iphone-sdk-3.0

I have several UITextFields. I want to disable the "double tap" that brings the autocorrection/keyboard. I'm using a tap function to chose which UITextField to activate.

Comment: A single tap brings up the keyboard -- what is the double-tap for?

Comment: single tap selects UITextField. When I double tap it brings up the keyboard. I won't to disable the double tap keyboard.

Comment: You must be creating a double-tap gesture then because the default behavior is to bring up the keyboard the first time you tap on a textfield. It doesn't "select" it on single tap.

Comment: code example:  tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapRecieved:)];
    tex2.userInteractionEnabled = YES;
    [tex2 addGestureRecognizer:tap];
 [tap release];
 tap = nil;

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can tell a UITextField not to begin the editing process using the `textFieldShouldBeginEditing` Delegate method of UITextView:

```
- (BOOL)textFieldShouldBeginEditing:(UITextField *)textField {
  if (some conditon) {
    return NO;
  } else {
    return YES;
  }
}
```

Apple documentation reference on the method:
http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#documentation/uikit/reference/UITextFieldDelegate_Protocol/UITextFieldDelegate/UITextFieldDelegate.html

`some condition` would likely be a check to see whether the user is selecting the UITextField to activate it, or whether it is already active and it should bring the keyboard up.

You could subclass UITextView to give it a "selected" property, and make it a UITextViewDelegate. If "selected" is false, then set it to true in `textFieldShouldBeginEditing:` and return NO; otherwise, return YES. That's just one random idea off the top of my head.

Comment: This is what I'm using to activate the the UITextfield. I just want to disable the editing keyboard(double tap). code example: tap = [[UITapGestureRecognizer alloc] initWithTarget:self action:@selector(tapRecieved:)]; tex2.userInteractionEnabled = YES; [tex2 addGestureRecognizer:tap]; [tap release]; tap = nil;